# Oracle is giving error while creating stored procedure. ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, sys-refcursor

Hi all I have requirement to pick records using dynamic pivoting in Oracle. I have done with my query which is working fine using "antonsPivoting" https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/.

When i add the query in procedure it gives error: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item.

Sample table script:

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT(DEPT_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, DEPT_NAME VARCHAR2(25))

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(EMP_ID NUMBER, EMP_NAME VARCHAR(100), DEPT_ID NUMBER , FOREIGN KEY(DEPT_ID) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DEPT_ID))


INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT(DEPT_ID, DEPT_NAME)
SELECT  1, 'HR' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'OPS' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'MKT' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'FIN' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'IT' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'SERV' FROM DUAL

COMMIT;


INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, DEPT_ID)

SELECT 1, 'A', 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'A', 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'B', 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'C', 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'D', 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'E', 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'F', 4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 7, 'G', 4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 8, 'H', 4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 9, 'I', 5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 10, 'J', 5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 11, 'K', 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 12, 'L', 1 FROM DUAL
COMMIT;
```

sample query script  working fine:

```
SELECT D.DEPT_NAME, COUNT(E.EMP_ID) TOTAL_EMP

FROM DEPARTMENT D
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE E ON D.DEPT_ID= E.DEPT_ID

GROUP BY D.DEPT_NAME
;
```

Dynamic pivoting example working fine:

```
select * from table( pivot(  '
SELECT D.DEPT_NAME, COUNT(E.EMP_ID) TOTAL_EMP

FROM DEPARTMENT D
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE E ON D.DEPT_ID= E.DEPT_ID

GROUP BY D.DEPT_NAME' ) )

;
```

adding in procedure which gives error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_EMPLOYEE (P_RESULT OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN 
    OPEN P_RESULT FOR
    select * from table( pivot(  '
SELECT D.DEPT_NAME, COUNT(E.EMP_ID) TOTAL_EMP

FROM DEPARTMENT D
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE E ON D.DEPT_ID= E.DEPT_ID

GROUP BY D.DEPT_NAME' ) )

;
    
END
;
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Although I had to add code for calling the procedure in SQL\*Plus: `variable v_cursor refcursor \n execute get_employee(:v_cursor) \n print :v_cursor'. What version of Oracle are you using - maybe the functions use some features not available in earlier versions.

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit
PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0

Comment: I'm not sure why it isn't working. Do you get the error at compile time or runtime? Is there a line number with the full error message?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the Pivot function ?

Please go through below link where this is already answered.

[Link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4086835?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Yes created and working fine in above query. Only when I add it into stored procedure gives error.

Comment: Could you please add your pivot function code as well to the question

Comment: large file unable to attach here: please download "AntonsPivoting.zip" from below URL

https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/

Thanks in advance.